# Pgfplots: xbar issues in histogram

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I want to create an histogram with grouped bars of the same color and around 
evenly spaced (arbitrary) `y-values`. I managed to get this:

[image]

Now, I want to put custom `ytick` labels in the center of each group, but I just do not understand how PGFPlots computes these values and I do not want to tinker with coordinates by trial-and-error.

Ideas?

======

**MWE**:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Title}

 How to put an ylabel in the exact center of each group of bars? (For that example, that would give coords like (0,55), (0,25), (0,-10) and (0,-50).)

 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       enlarge y limits=4,
       xbar,
       xmin=0,
       bar width=7pt,
    ]
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.387,0) };
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.199,0) };
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.192,0) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.145,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.142,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.137,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.132,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.131,5) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.104,10) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.103,10) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.098,10) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.143,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.141,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.137,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.120,15) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Any special reason for your preference on Torbjorn's answer instead of mine?

Comment: @Cragfelt I'm not the OP, but you appear to have done exactly what Bibi said he/she wanted to avoid: tinker with coordinates by trial and error.

Comment: @Cragfelt: Torbjorn is right, for your answer you need to specify the `ytick` coordinates explicitly with trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `xbar` to the `\addplot` options instead of the `axis` options, the bars are placed at the given y-values. So you can use one `\addplot` per group, with different y-values. There is no need to guess the y-values, as you choose the middle one for the group. E.g. with bars at `y = 0,1,2`, place the `ytick` at `y = 1`.

[image: output]

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Title}

 How to put an ylabel in the exact center of each group of bars? (For that example, that would give coords like (0,55), (0,25), (0,-10) and (0,-50).)

 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       enlarge y limits=0.1,
       xmin=0,
       bar width=5pt,
       ytick={1,6,11,15.5},
       yticklabels={foo,bar,baz,foobar},
       tickwidth=0pt
    ]
       \addplot[xbar,fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.387,0)(0.199,1)(0.192,2) };
       \addplot[xbar,fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.145,4)(0.142,5)(0.137,6)(0.132,7)(0.131,8) };
       \addplot[xbar,fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.104,10)(0.103,11)(0.098,12) };
       \addplot[xbar,fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.143,14)(0.141,15)(0.137,16)(0.120,17) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Title}

 How to put an ylabel in the exact center of each group of bars? (For that example, that would give coords like (0,55), (0,25), (0,-10) and (0,-50).)

 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       enlarge y limits=4,
       xbar,
       xmin=0,
       bar width=7pt,
       ytick=\empty,
       extra y ticks={-45,-10,25,56},
       extra y tick labels={$-50$, $-10$, $25$, $55$},
    ]
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.387,0) };
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.199,0) };
       \addplot[fill=blue!20] coordinates { (0.192,0) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.145,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.142,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.137,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.132,5) };
       \addplot[fill=green!20] coordinates { (0.131,5) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.104,10) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.103,10) };
       \addplot[fill=red!20] coordinates { (0.098,10) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.143,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.141,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.137,15) };
       \addplot[fill=orange!20] coordinates { (0.120,15) };
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```